# Can Kiwi TCMS reports ID issue to Bugzilla?

Tags: foreign-keys, integration, bugzilla, kiwi-tcms

1) I have a question about KIWI TCMS and Bugzilla integration. Now our integration works by first having to create bugs in Bugzilla and then enter the bug number into KIWI TCMS and pair each other.

I wonder if there is a chance to create an automatic Bugzilla issue from KIWI TCMS. Without having to set up first a Bugzilla issue. Whether it could be created automatically.

2) Can I set bug tracking number in Bugzilla different then default? For example, set BUG-XY, BUG-01, BUG-02.. Now I have in bugzilla only numbers.

Thanks for info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, see the attached picture. The "Report" link is right next to the "Add" link which you have been using. When you click it Kiwi TCMS will try to connect to your Bugzilla instance and report the bug automatically, linking back to the test case which failed.

[image]

That said you will have to configure your Bugzilla URL and login credentials for this to work. See the documentation at https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers